# не могу решить проблему подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
<%
program_mega_test = ArrayOptFirstElem(XQuery("for $elem in test_learnings where $elem/assessment_id = 6872249034465500974 and $elem/person_id = " + adapt_top.person_id + 
" and $elem/max_score = $elem/score order by $elem/score descending return $elem"));
if(last_block.typical_development_program_id == 6877825654678515140 && program_mega_test != undefined ){
    %> // 2 часть
```

good">✔
            Получение доступов

```
    <div class="progress-line v-middle" style="height: 0.3em; margin: 0 4em; text-align: right">
        <div class="current-progress" style="height: 0.3em; width: <%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%;"></div>
        <div class="current-progress-title font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%</div>
        <div class="current-progress-desc font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>1<%}else{%>0<%}%>/1 выполнено</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="switch-panel-content" id="switch-panel-content-mail">
    <p>Поздравляем, ты успешно аттестован для продажи продуктов:</p>
    <p>✔ MoneyCare</p>
    <p>✔ Халва</p>
    <p>✔ Д2</p>
    <p>✔ РГС</p>
    <p>✔ СТОЛОТО</p>
    <br/>
    <p>Для получения письма с подтверждением аттестации нажми здесь:</p>
    <div class="button" onclick="SendMail()">Получить письмо</div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>Письмо придет автоматически на почту, его необходимо будет переслать с вложением на адрес эл.почты: <a href="mailto:test@test.ru">test@test.ru</a></p>
</div> //2 часть
```

```
 <%                           
            due_date = OpenDoc(UrlFromDocID(OptInt(block.typical_development_program_id))).TopElem.tasks[0].due_date;
            if(last_block == "" || (last_block != "" && OpenDoc(UrlFromDocID(OptInt(last_block.typical_development_program_id))).TopElem.tasks[0].due_date != due_date)){       
        //if(last_block.typical_development_program_id == 6877825654678515140){
            program_mega_test = ArrayOptFirstElem(XQuery("for $elem in test_learnings where $elem/assessment_id = 6872249034465500974 and $elem/person_id = " + adapt_top.person_id + 
            " and $elem/max_score = $elem/score order by $elem/score descending return $elem"));
            if( 0 != undefined ){
%> //1 часть
```

good">✔
                                    Получение доступов

```
                            <div class="progress-line v-middle" style="height: 0.3em; margin: 0 4em; text-align: right">
                                <div class="current-progress" style="height: 0.3em; width: <%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%;"></div>
                                <div class="current-progress-title font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%</div>
                                <div class="current-progress-desc font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>1<%}else{%>0<%}%>/1 выполнено</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="switch-panel-content" id="switch-panel-content-mail">
                            <p>Поздравляем, ты успешно аттестован для продажи продуктов:</p>
                            <p>✔ MoneyCare</p>
                            <p>✔ Халва</p>
                            <p>✔ Д2</p>
                            <p>✔ РГС</p>
                            <p>✔ СТОЛОТО</p>
                            <br/>
                            <p>Для получения письма с подтверждением аттестации нажми здесь:</p>
                            <div class="button" onclick="SendMail()">Получить письмо</div>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <p>Письмо придет автоматически на почту, его необходимо будет переслать с вложением на адрес эл.почты: <a href="mailto:test@test.ru">test@test.ru</a></p>
                        </div>
```

//1 часть

```
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++ ){
        let indx = i;
    if(document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i) != null){
            document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i).addEventListener("click",  () => { SwitchPanel(indx); }, false);
    }
    }

function SwitchPanel(num){
    panel = document.getElementById('switch-panel-content-' + num);
    if(panel.style.display == "block"){
        panel.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + num).classList.remove("switch-selected");
    }
    else{
        panel.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + num).classList.add("switch-selected");
    }
} //функция
```

//Ошибка выдает
Uncaught ReferenceError: SwitchPanel is not defined
at HTMLDivElement.onclick (view_doc.html?mode=adapt_card&doc_id=&adapt_id=7112696512017738677:370:143)
показывает то что проблема в этом части

```
<div class="switch-panel justify-space-between" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;"  id="switch-panel-mail" onclick="SwitchPanel('mail')">
```

[image: написано такое ошибка]

Comment: Попробуй сначала объявить функцию, а потом её указывать и вызывать.

Comment: Уверен, что в разметке есть элементы с id "switch-panel-0" по "switch-panel-6"?

Comment: c id="swith-panel-0" нету есть только
1.id="switch-panel-mail"
2.id="switch-panel-content-mail"

Comment: А зачем в таком случае нужна эта запись: `document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i)`?

Comment: тут при прохождения теста должен нажаться кнопка и оно должен отправлять на почту чтоб условия сразу автоматический сам дал ему доступ чтоб он мог дальше проходить курсы 
Пример после того как он ответил на 20 вопросов для того чтобы пройти дальше курсы ему должен отрыться этот панель которое я поставил код при нажатия получить доступ автоматический добавится ему другой блок с курсами

Comment: document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i) он берет данные человека и проверяет он ответил на все 20 вопросов правильно или нет если нет то доступ закрыть если ответил правильно на 20 то его пропускает дальше чтоб прошел другие блоки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема показывает на этот часть кода

```
<div class="switch-panel justify-space-between" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;"  id="switch-panel-mail" onclick="SwitchPanel('mail')">

(Uncaught ReferenceError: SwitchPanel is not defined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй снчала функцию объявить, а потом её вызывать.

```
function SwitchPanel(num){
    panel = document.getElementById('switch-panel-content-' + num);
    if(panel.style.display == "block"){
        panel.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + num).classList.remove("switch-selected");
    }
    else{
        panel.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + num).classList.add("switch-selected");
    }
} //функция

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++ ){
        let indx = i;
    if(document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i) != null){
            document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i).addEventListener("click",  () => { SwitchPanel(indx); }, false);
    }
    }
```

Comment: сделал та же ошибка !